# Не присвоилась репутация за внесение правок

Tags: поддержка, репутация, предлагаемые-правки

По какой-то непонятной причине, после последних внесенных мною и утвержденных модераторами правок, не была начислена репутация. Репутация заморозилась на отметке 1240 опыта, спустя час стала +2, а остальная, где?  Возможно, это какой-то баг на сервере, может быть кто-то тоже столкнулся с подобным?  Сделал скриншоты на всякий, чтоб наглядней было:
[1-й](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1QJx_nil7jaMzombaZWLCaV4TM75dkAAM)
[2-й](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1bo3ORVW2gIclOURl2kAAmKED9YnPfRxn)
[3-й](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1MW30puXAsXiZFbFe0nUVrJXQDvw31q7x)

На последнем скриншоте добавились еще 2 правки утвержденные модераторами и так-же, ничего.

Comment: Учитывая, что у вас 537 предложенных правок, подозреваю, вы уже заработали свои [+1000 на правках](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Comment: @Nofate Скорее всего, а разве дальше вступают какие-то ограничения?

Comment: Дальше правки бесплатны )

Comment: @Nofate Понятно, но вопрос оставлю, так как подобного на мете не нашел, вдруг кто-то тоже запаникует )

Comment: Сообшество потеряло через это странное ограничение ценнейшего редактора в лице Влада. Предложение - поднять потолок.

Comment: @0xdb Почему потеряло? Я на месте Дмитрий, продолжаем в том же духе. Может не так рьяно, но я ж теперь `"Главред"`, теперь по долгу службы обязан )))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ваш профиль показывает [537 предложенных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262779/vlad-spirin?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) и [529 одобренных](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/262779/vlad-spirin?tab=activity&sort=revisions) правок. +2 репутации за каждую правку уже набрали вам 1000 баллов — [потолок](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) для поощрений за этот вид деятельности в нашем сообществе.

Спасибо за этот немалый вклад. Дальнейшие правки потребуют от вас альтруизма, надеюсь, что вас это не остановит.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ, не оставит само собой, тут прекрасное сообщество с грамотными людьми, всегда есть чему поучиться.

Comment: Хм.. А я где-то про 4000 читал...

Comment: @Qwertiy тогда, по идее, в этом "где-то" и привилегия редактирования без проверки должна даваться не раньше 4к репутации. Ибо репутация даётся только за _принятые предложенные_ правки.

Comment: @Regent, я читал, что только за предлаггаемые правки (репутация меньше 2К) но не более 4К суммарно. Репутацию же ещё и тратить можно - на конкурсы, например.